# Rebuid only modules that contains warnings

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator, compiler-warnings

For now i'm working on complicated Qt project and trying to eliminate many of warnings which appears when i'm trying to build project with using of different compilers (gcc,clang,msvc). Full rebuild of project takes up a long time.

Is there a some tool or maybe a artful approach to rebuild only modules that has warnings on previous build?

I think it might be reached by deleting (or outdating) those modules. Thus Make utility can rebuild them for me.

Comment: Just a simple build - rebuilds the the modules that you made changes into. Full rebuild means rebuild all modules no matter what..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the earlier comment say, only do a normal build. Anything that didn't compile last time will now compile. This of cause requires that you set a compiler flag to treat warnings as error or the compiler will create object files even though there are warnings. And the above strategy will fail.

Comment: Treat warnins as error exactly what I need. Thanks. But another question is how to set this option to all of related projects.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014947/how-to-add-warnings-as-error-rule-to-qt-pro-file) post for info on setting warnings as errors in Qt projects. Don't know if it works on all compilers though.